# Is the verb create being used in passive voice?

Tags: vocabulary, passive-voice

From the page ["How to Use Javascript Arrow Functions:"](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/how-to-use-javascript-arrow-functions-and-this-keyword/)

> **What are the arrow functions**
>
> It is a sort of an abbreviated way to write compact functions.
>
> One of the main differences between arrow functions and regular functions is that arrow functions can only be anonymous. They are not bound to any identifier.
>
> **Thus they created dynamically.** We cannot name an arrow function as we do for the regular functions. However, if you'd like to call or reuse an arrow function, you will need to assign it to a variable.

The text talks about the syntax of creating arrow function in javascript, it had me confused on: "Thus they created dynamically" part, because arrow functions does not create themself. A programmer has to do so. Shouldn't that be: "Thus they are created dynamically"???

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's based on bad grammar, so no learning can come from it

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is a typo. The correct sentence is "Thus they *are* created dynamically" which is in the passive voice.

The language on that page is not of the highest quality. For the most part it is correct, but there are some errors (like the one you found) and the tone used is not consistent.